# Show Alert in clickedButtonAtIndex?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uialertview

i need to show a confirm alert after the user press `buttonIndex 1` but... if i use `popViewcontroller` in `clickedButtonAtIndex` it crash without errors.

The problem is that

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

is called before second Alert click...

how to fix?

This is my code:

```
- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        UIAlertView *alert = 
            [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"OK!"
                                    message:@"Completed"
                                    delegate:self 
                    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show]; 
            [alert release];

            [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: I once made a subclass of UIAlertView just because one cannot click on a touch screen. The dude who named this delegate has a special place in hell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the tag properties of the two UIAlertViews to 1 and 2, respectively. Then, in the delegate method, use if statements to check the tag of the UIAlertView argument.

Example:

```
- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (alertView.tag == 1)
    {
        //check the button index
        //create and display the other alert view (set the tag property here to 2)
    }
    else if (alertView.tag == 2)
    {
        //pop the view controller
    }
}
```